# Failure to import bean definition file

Tags: eclipse, spring, import, classpath, javabeans

I have an Eclipse Mars project compiling to a jar file with a Spring bean definition file in the following path: `my-project.jar/spring/config.xml`

This artifact is included in another Eclipse webapp project (via Maven). When I expand the contents of the compiled war file, I can see that the my-project.jar file and its contents (i.e. config.xml) exist.

Inside the webapp, I have a Spring definition file `(WEB-INF/classes/spring/context.xml)` and it has an import statement for config.xml as follows:          `<import resource="classpath:spring/config.xml"/>`

I run into issues, when I launch the webapp (via Eclipse). I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [data.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:spring/config.xml]
```

The file is in the classpath, so I assume there is some class loader issue that I can't figure out. Strangely, this issue is inconsistent. There was once or twice that starting up the webapp produced no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Put a slash in front when your bean definition XML file is in some folder:

```
<import resource="classpath:/spring/config.xml"/>
```